# Proof of partial fraction decomposition without using complex numbers and properties of complex field

Tags: partial-fractions

Does somebody know the proof of partial fraction decomposition theorem for rational functions over field of real numbers that does not use properties of field of complex numbers?

Comment: Does [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Basic_principles) help?

Comment: little... using Euclidean algorithm and Bézout's identity for polynomials in order to (rigorously) proof general case makes a lot of mess...

Comment: if somebody can write (or give a link to) a detailed proof would be satisfactory

Comment: If you know linear algebra, [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/33943) may help.